# Using ecryptfs in Windows Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, windows-10

I'm trying to create an encrypted folder in Windows Ubuntu shell (Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS). I managed to install it correctly but when I tried to create an encrypted folder using the command:

```
sudo mount -t ecryptfs /home/secure/ /home/secure/
```

I got the error

```
Exiting. Unable to mlockall address space: Function not implemented
```

How can I fix this issue or is there an alternative that might work?

Comment: You have BitLocker for Windows. I think the "Function not implemented" says it all, can't be done, but I can be wrong...

Comment: I'm looking for something I can run natively on the Ubuntu shell (within Windows)

Comment: Since this is specific to Windows, hop on over to superuser to get more information. You may want to start here: https://superuser.com/questions/667902/mount-ecryptfs-volume-on-windows